# Test suite generator for guava project

Tags: guava

In the google-collections gtug videos there was a mention of test suite generator and plans to open source it.

Currently in guava git project there are two maven modules

1. guava-testlib
2. guava-tests

Are these two modules the next version of the test suite generator?

At cursory glance the code within these modules seemed very much specific to guava project.

Is there an easy way to utilize the library/code/strategies used in test suite generator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the automatic test suite generator for testing collection implementations is the bulk of what's in guava-testlib. [This post](http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/2012/09/google-guava-collection-test-suite/) explains how to use it.

Comment: I am hoping that I can reuse this in one of my projects, this link can help me get started, thanks Kevin.